# Here-api Autosuggest occasionally returns 401 Unauthorized when proxied through server

Tags: apache, here-api, autosuggest

We have set up Apache to proxy requests made from a browser site to (Here api) Autosuggest endpoint. The request is proxied through our server to avoid the browser throwing a Cross Origin Request (CORS) error, which happens when making the request directly from a browser.

The proxy is configured on Apache in the .conf file like so:

```
<Location /here-autosuggest>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest
        ProxyPassReverse https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest
</Location>
```

This setup has been working on our production system for a year. However, we occasionally face this problem which can last hours, before the API starts returning valid results again. So far this has happened about 5 times in the past 8 months.

However, calling the endpoint directly (https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest) with Postman (a rest client) works fine, returning valid results. But making the call via our server proxy (https://our-domain/here-autosuggest) using Postman will return 401.

After some time (normally 7+ hours), calls via our proxy work again and will continue to work successfully for the foreseeable future without us changing a thing.

We suspect Here might be blocking calls from our server address temporarily.

Is this possible, and is there anything we can do mitigate this if our server requests are being blocked?

Comment: This is really weird, can you tell me if you are using freemium or if you are using a paid plan? Also, what's an estimate for your load when you get this error?

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. Yes, we are on freemium as we are not currently near the monthly transaction limits. The load is no more than around 40 requests per minute.

Answer (score 0):

Here API does not block any request for its API.
There might be two reasons for which you have experienced such a different behavior.

1. There might be the case that sometimes it might have crossed freemium plan limits.
2. There was some maintenance work done in the recent past.

Comment: Hi, much appreciated for your response. However, I don't think the reasons listed would explain why requests made from my local machine were all successful, yet those made via our server returned 401.